# Are there any standard way to implement the "blue badge" in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

A lot of iPhone apps use a blue badge to indicate the number of items in the subviews, such as the Mail client:

[iPhoto http://img.skitch.com/20081103-tjr9yupbhgr3sqfh7u56if4rsn.preview.jpg](http://skitch.com/leonho/4xeu/iphoto)

Are there any standards way (or even an API) do this?

UPDATE: I have created a class called BlueBadge to do this. It is available at http://github.com/leonho/iphone-libs/tree/master

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no API for this. However, using CoreGraphics (NSBezierPath is not available on iPhone), you can do it pretty easily. It's just two arcs in a CGPath and some text:

```
CGContextRef        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
float               radius = bounds.size.height / 2.0;
NSString            *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", count];

CGContextClearRect(context, bounds);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, ovalColor);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, radius, radius, radius, M_PI / 2 , 3 * M_PI / 2, NO);
CGContextAddArc(context, bounds.size.width - radius, radius, radius, 3 * M_PI / 2, M_PI / 2, NO);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];

UIFont              *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14];
CGSize              numberSize = [countString sizeWithFont: font];

bounds.origin.x = (bounds.size.width - numberSize.width) / 2;

[countString drawInRect: bounds withFont: font];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way to implement something very close to the `UITabBarItem` badge is to use the `UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` method where both end caps could be a fancier image and the middle will be strech automatically (using the 1px wide image) to fit the `NSString` size that would be overlaid on top.

Still need to get the proper images but that could be easily pulled from a screenshot or constructed from PS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily and flexibly by using a simple UILabel and changing the cornerRadius of its underlaying layer:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> // don't forget!
// ...
UILabel *badge = [[UILabel alloc] init];
badge.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
badge.layer.cornerRadius = badge.bounds.size.height / 2;
```

You can use my (small and simple) [code for a BadgeLabel class and a matching BadgeTableViewCell class](http://ootips.org/yonat/badge-label/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods in the NSBezierPath class called "appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect....".

I havent tried them out myself, but they might work. It's worth a try.

Answer (score -7):

There is also another type of badge that you might already know, it's the "red" one that is on the application icon. They are created by doing something like:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSString *caldate = [[now 
        dateWithCalendarFormat:@"%b" 
        timeZone:nil] description];
[self setApplicationBadge:caldate];"
```

this will set the badge with a 3 letter abbreviation for the current month.