# CoreGraphics on iPhone, trying to draw a "pill" type ellipse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a pill type ellipse, as in Apple's Mail application which displays the number of emails in the inbox. Any idea why the following isn't drawing?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{ 
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat minX = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
    CGFloat minY = CGRectGetMinY(rect);
    CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
    CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

    CGFloat radius = 3.0; 
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, (minX + maxX) / 2.0, minY);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minX, minY, minX, maxY, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minX, maxY, maxX, maxY, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxX, maxY, maxX, minY, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxX, minY, minX, minY, radius);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've forgotten to set the fill color.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258375/are-there-any-standard-way-to-implement-the-blue-badge-in-iphone) for code to do exactly what you require.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the answer. I wish I found that prior to posting and wasting everyone's bandwidth.  Thanks rpetrich.

Comment: No problem. The old question wasn't easy to find; it took me a few mins and I knew it was there.