# Using Badge Subview of TabBarItem Elsewhere

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Since Apple doesn't seem to provide a public means of creating notification badges wherever you like, I was wondering if it was;

A) Possible to reference the subview of a tabbar/tabbaritem that is the badge indicator?
B) If so, is it kosher to use/duplicate this view for use within my own view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help ? [Are there any standard way to implement the "blue badge" in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258375/are-there-any-standard-way-to-implement-the-blue-badge-in-iphone)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that helps a bit.  I did, however, find a nice class at http://www.claireware.com/blog_files/iphone_badge_view.html